# clickhouse calculate the average

Tags: average, clickhouse

I have two Field,one is timestamp,another is sum of network in bytes.just like this:

```
timestamp      network_in_bytes
1551196802144   1
1551196802145   5 
1551196802147   18 
1551196802158   80
```

I want to calculate(B>A)

```
avg_network_in_bytes=(network_in_bytes_B-network_in_bytes_A)/(timestamp_B-timestamp_A).
```

How do I get the avg_network_in_bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this function [runningDifference](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/other_functions/#other_functions-runningdifference)

You can try to do something like this:

```sql
select 
  timestamp,
  network_in_bytes,
  runningDifference(timestamp) as timestamp_diff,
  runningDifference(network_in_bytes) as bytes_diff,
  bytes_diff / timestamp_diff
from (
  select
    timestamp,
    network_in_bytes
  from table
  order by timestamp 
)
```